# setinterval says not defined function but it is

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

i have this function which i define inside HEAD:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js">
function live() {
    $.get("http://mydomain.com/script.php", function(data){
        var timer = data;
        var elm = document.getElementById("live");
        if (timer == 1){
         elm.style.display = 'block';
        } else{
         elm.style.display = 'none';
        }     
    });
}
</script>
```

and then i do a loop like this at the very end of my document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 setInterval(live,10000);
</script>
```

but i get an error saying live is not defined. Why is that? Could you please tell me what im doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you check in firebug if you got any error in your javascript?

Comment: Yes, i only get this ReferenceError: live is not defined

Answer (score 6):

Put your code in an separate `<script>` tag. As soon as a `<script>` tag has a `src` attribute, any content of that tag is ignored in favor of the given resource. so just do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function live() {
    $.get("http://mydomain.com/script.php", function(data){
        var timer = data;
        var elm = document.getElementById("live");
        if (timer == 1){
         elm.style.display = 'block';
        } else{
         elm.style.display = 'none';
        }     
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, now it says $.get is not a function

Comment: @Nuker [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/T5yEE/). Any other possible conflicts? Correct order of `<script>` tags, successful loading of the given jQuery ?